# loss.backward() gives RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to use BCELoss without any success.

```
loss = BCELoss()
opt   = optim.AdamW  (model.parameters(), lr=0.01, betas=(0.9, 0.99), weight_decay=0.001)
```

```
loss = Loss(z, y)
opt.zero_grad() 
loss.backward()
```

z, y have the shape: (128, 2)

I'm getting error (from `loss.backward()`):

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

When using `CrossEntropyLoss` (and y has the shape of `(128,)`) all works !

1. what is wrong ?
2. what do I need to change ?

Answer (score 0):

Binary Cross Entropy or [`BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html?highlight=bceloss#torch.nn.BCELoss) requires every sample to have one number between `[0, 1]`.

Your `z` needs to be `[128,]` (float and within [0,1]) and `y` to be `[128,]` (long integer containing only 0 and 1).