# Getting Cuda error if I use BCE loss and works fine with BCEWithLogitsLoss but getting huge losses

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am working on SRGAN model and I created the model and used MSE loss and BCE loss functions to calculate image losses.

If I use BCEWithLogitsLoss, then the code works but theres huge losses. But I tried using BCE loss and it throws CUDA error. Can someone suggest me where did i went wrong and how can I fix the cuda error.

Optimizers are Adam with learning rate 0.0001

Attached the generator and discriminator

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,  no_of_blocks=16):
super(Generator, self).__init__()

#First layer
self.CV_Block1 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=9, stride=1, padding=4),
    nn.PReLU())

#Residual Blocks
Blocks = []
for _ in range(no_of_blocks):
  Blocks.append(Residual_Block(64))
self.Blocks = nn.Sequential(*Blocks)

# Second convolution layer
self.CV_Block3 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(64, 0.8)
)

# self.Upsample = nn.Sequential(
#     UP_Sampling(64, 2),
#     UP_Sampling(64, 2)
# )

upsampling = []
for _ in range(2):
  upsampling.append(UP_Sampling(64))
self.upsampling = nn.Sequential(*upsampling)


#Final Layer
self.CV_Block_end = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(64, 3, kernel_size=9, stride=1, padding=4),
    nn.Tanh()
)

# self._initialize_weights()

def forward(self, x): #: torch.Tensor
CV1_out = self.CV_Block1(x)
Res_Out = self.Blocks(CV1_out)
CV3_Out = self.CV_Block3(Res_Out)
out = torch.add(CV1_out, CV3_Out)
out = self.upsampling(out)
out = self.CV_Block_end(out)

# out = torch.clamp_(out, 0.0, 1.0)
# gen_out = self.CV_Block_end(x)
return out




class Discriminator(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,input_shape):
    super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
    # self.input_shape = input_shape
    # in_height, in_width = self.input_shape
    # patch_h, patch_w = int(in_height / 2 ** 4), int(in_width / 2 ** 4)
    # self.output_shape = (1, patch_h, patch_w)
    self.features = nn.Sequential(
        # input size. (3) x 96 x 96
        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, (3, 3), (1, 1), (1, 1), bias=True),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        # state size. (64) x 48 x 48
        nn.Conv2d(64, 64, (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 128, (3, 3), (1, 1), (1, 1), bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        # state size. (128) x 24 x 24
        nn.Conv2d(128, 128, (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        nn.Conv2d(128, 256, (3, 3), (1, 1), (1, 1), bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        # state size. (256) x 12 x 12
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 512, (3, 3), (1, 1), (1, 1), bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        # state size. (512) x 6 x 6
        nn.Conv2d(512, 512, (3, 3), (2, 2), (1, 1), bias=False),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(512),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
    )

    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(512 * 6 * 6, 1024),
        nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, True),
        nn.Linear(1024, 1),
        nn.Sigmoid(),
    )

def forward(self, x):
    out = self.features(x)
    # out = torch.flatten(out, 1)
    # out = self.classifier(out)

    return out
```

[image]

Comment: With the BCE Loss, can you restart the Python kernel? Or you can follow the instruction, set `CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1`, you can run it by `os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Error "device-side assert triggered" triggered inside BCELoss when inputs not in [0..1] (so it not a probabilities).

You got it because remove block `classifier` block with nn.Sigmoid

```
# out = self.classifier(out)
```

There a similar question:
[loss.backward() gives RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045245/loss-backward-gives-runtimeerror-cuda-error-device-side-assert-triggered)